# Split a dependent clause from an independent clause

Tags: punctuation, dependent-clause, comma-splices

The first clause in the following sentence has no subject, nor verb:

> From the first agricultural settlements to the rich Emirates of the
>   Arabian peninsula, the Middle East has always had an important
>   significance for the world since its rise.

Is a comma possible? Or should I split the clauses by a colon, semi-colon, or maybe an em-dash; however, I've read all can't be used with dependent clauses.

Comment: There is something wrong with the main clause: "...since its rise." implies a period that began in the past but which continues into the present, so "already had", which necessarily refers to something that had occurred ('already') before a definite time in the past. Do you mean something like " ...has always had... from the beginnings of human history "?

Comment: I will change it. The sentence was translated from Dutch, but the structure, however, remains the same.

Comment: What you are calling a dependent clause is not a clause at all, but two coordinated preposition phrases: "from ... to ...". They function as supplements, and the comma is fine.

Comment: your title:  form = from?